# jQuery selections give SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL (Meteor / WebStorm)

Tags: jquery, meteor, webstorm

So all my jQuery selections are giving me problems in my WebStorm 11.0.3 Meteor project. For example:

```
$("#fmeserverurl").val("asdf")
```

gives this error (exactly):

```
"fmeserverur = SyntaxError : Unexpected Token ILLEGAL
```

Not sure if its important but to be sure: so the error message is without the last **l** character of fmeserverur**l** and without the closing quote: **"** .

This is the case for each selection.. so always the last character is dropped and the closing quote "

I have tried with single quotes instead of double quotes.. tried to retype the selection (its not copied from somewhere so no hidden characters I guess as is suggested in other threads concerning Unexpected Token ILLEGAL error messages).

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

In response to question for lines before/after:

This happens all over the place, so unrelated to the context. But for example:

```
renderedWithSubsReady(Template.vcs_vcm_widgets_Export, function(){
    var data = this.data.data;
    $("#fmeserverurl").val(data.fmeserverurl ? data.fmeserverurl : "");
    $("#fmeuser").val(data.fmeuser ? data.fmeuser : "");
    ..
    ..
```

Comment: Can you show us the full code including the lines below and above the current line?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334893/unexpected-token-illegal-javascript-meteor, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal. Most likely you have some inproperly terminated string literals somewhere in your code

Comment: Yes, I read those comments. But does that mean that if I have in the code at one place some inproperly terminated string literal that **all** of my jquery selections get broken?